# What are the different types of hashes given in the release notes of each runtime used for?

Tags: polkadot

A runtime release might say the following:

```
️ system.setCode hash:        0xa6b93db1b6abbe5c94e4fe0969f86eed61d78fda7e0405bfe7b1a2b4d87d4a4f
️ authorizeUpgrade hash:  0x055361413e61894180c2b331b27ecfb34711aa188ae46a8d729001a1dd089d6e
#️⃣ Blake2-256 hash:        0x85cbef6d0e24bf3081fdd1e484fbf0ad510292aeb7d01fa27ae59d705466fd86
 IPFS:            QmVqUxwE8zoCZrxVM4nHEQPuQKfZyCMPS65hfojEY3EdME
```

(this one happens to be as statemine release but they all follow a pattern)

The IPFS is the content addressable hash for IPFS, but what are the other hashes used for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output that is mentioned here and in the release notes actually comes from  [subwasm](https://github.com/chevdor/subwasm) and is internally called by [srtool](https://github.com/paritytech/srtool).

Historically, **srtool** used a sha256 to compare WASM runtimes. While it worked for the comparison, sha256 in that context was rather useless and has been removed. It has been replaced by the `system.setCode` hash which is the scale encoding of `<module> / <call> / <data>` so in our case `system / setCode / runtime`.

While also usable to compare runtimes, `system.setCode` is much more useful and has a direct use since it is also the one required to propose a runtime upgrade on a relay chain directly. It became the de-facto hash that represents a runtime.

The IPFS hash is rather unrelated but convenient as it allows fetching the runtime from IPFS **if this runtime is seeded**. **srtool** and **subwasm** do not seed the runtime on IPFS but compute the hash of the data. So if one or more users seeded this runtime, you can easily fetch it using https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmVqUxwE8zoCZrxVM4nHEQPuQKfZyCMPS65hfojEY3EdME for the hash mentioned in the OP.

The 2 other hashes (`authorizeUpgrade hash` and `Blake2-256 hash`) are utilities that ease the creation of more complex proposals mainly related to sending parachain upgrade messages from the relay chain.